# Given the formula for magnetic field, if I integrate it with respect to distance, can I plug in values before integrating?

Tags: calculus

Ok, so lets say I have some function $P(t, r)$ which gives me the magnetic at any radial distance r at time t.

If I want to integrate $P(t, r)$ at $t=10s$ with respect to r, can I integrate $P(10, r)$ to get my answer? Or do I have to first integrate $P(t, r)$ and then plug in $t=10s$ to my new quantity?

Comment: I'm 90% I understand your question, but could you give some concrete examples.  Like, let $P(t,r)=tr$ or $t+r$ or something simple like that, and show what the two different integrals would look like.  I think you might end up answering your own question that way.

Comment: Ok, something like P(t,r) = tr.  I know how to integrate P(r) = tr with with respect to r, and P(t) = tr with respect to t, but I'm confused about integrating a quantity that actually depends on time and distance.  I know that we can pull constants out of the integral, but I'm confused since the magnetic field depends on both time and distance

Comment: As $t$ and $r$ are independent variables (as in $t \ne t(r)$), it won't matter whether you integrate wrt $r$ first and then plug in $t=10$, or plug in first.  In the integral you'll treat $t$ as a constant anyway.